# Why isn't 0 in the real numbers a counterexample to left cosets having equal size?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've just seen a proof that shows that all left cosets of a given subgroup $H$ have equal size. I've had a hard time convincing myself of this result, partially because I don't understand how it holds, for, say, letting $H = \mathbb{Z}$. If our main group is $\mathbb{R}$ under multiplication, then $0\mathbb{Z} = \{0\}$, but $a\mathbb{Z} = \{an | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ in general, so the cardinality of almost all cosets is countably infinite, but exactly 1 for one coset. How can I reconcile this?

Comment: Does the fact that $0$ has no inverse under multiplication suggest a resolution?

Comment: Yes, it does. I feel pretty silly now.

Comment: Also realize that $\mathbb Z$ would not be a subgroup for it, as $2^{-1}$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\mathbb R$ with multiplication is not a group